# Factoring, Substituting and printing roots of a polynomial

Tags: python

We've been asked to make a program that takes in polynomial coefficients(i.e. [1, 2, 1] representing x^2 + 2x + 1 and use the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to find and print the roots in a list of fractional strings. We were only allowed to use import math. The problem with my code is it only works if I input [1, 2, 1] and when I input other polynomials, it prints a blank list.

```
import math

roots = []
pr = []
pf = []
qf = []
count = 1 
t = 0

co = raw_input('Input Coefficients: ')
co = co.split(' ')

p = co[0]
q = co[-1]


def gcd(a,b): #function for computing gcf between two numbers. will be used to simplify fractions into lowest terms
    r = a%b     
    if r == 0:
        return b
    else:
        return gcd(b,r) 


def rmvvalues(coefficients, val): #remove the zeroes from the list because zero is not factorable
    for i in range(coefficients.count(val)):
        coefficients.remove(val)

while int(p) == 0: #if the constant was 0, it means 0 is automatically a root
    roots.append(0)
    rmvvalues(co, str('0'))
    p = co[0]
    q = co[-1]

while count <= math.fabs(int(p)): #factors of the constant
    if int(p) % count == 0:
        pf.append(count)
        pf.append(count*(-1))
        count = count + 1
    else:
        count = count + 1

count = 1

while count <= math.fabs(int(q)): #factors of the last term
    if int(q) % count == 0:
        qf.append(count)
        qf.append(count*(-1))
        count = count + 1
    else:
        count = count + 1

count = 1

for i in range(len(pf)): #every element in the first list of factors is to be divided by every element of the other list of factors
    for j in range(len(qf)): 
        result = 0

        for c in range(len(co)): #and each pf/qf is to be checked if it would make the polynomial zero
            result = int(result) * (int(pf[i])/int(qf[j])) + int(co[c])

        if result == 0: #if it makes it zero, it appends the answer in fraction string to the list of roots
            if (int(pf[i]) / int(qf[j])) == 1: #add 1 to the list of roots if p/q == 1 and would make the equation zero
                roots.append(1)
            elif int(pf[i])/int(qf[j]) == -1: #add -1 to the list of roots if p/q == -1 and would make the equation zero
                roots.append(-1)
            else: #if they would be fractions
                a = int(pf[i]) / int(gcd(int(pf[i]),int(qf[j])))
                b = int(qf[j]) / int(gcd(int(pf[i]),int(qf[j])))
                roots.append(str(a) + '/' +str(b))
            roots = sorted(set(roots))

print roots
```

p.s.(I just copy/pasted the code from my editor so the indentation may be a little off)

Comment: Comment your code please! In instance we have to read all the function to see how they are supposed to works together. Instead each function should be understandale by itself by reading it's comments, use `"""Function comment here"""` to add comments after function name and before function code.  Also adding comment concerning the algorithm you are using and references to external source describing it could help us to help you to debug your code.

Comment: It doesn't appear as though you actually use the `gcd` function.

Comment: oh sorry I forgot to include it in

Comment: Do you use big-endian or little-endian representation for the list of coefficients?

Answer (score 0):

I have an implementation to propose, but not a debugging of yours.
The fact is that you are writing a big one bloc code that I don't understand.
As I want to help you I give you an example of implementation that I hope you will find helpful AND readable. My big suggest when coding is to split the code in little function easy to understand with meaningful name, and then add an algorithm function that call all the sub-functions. This make the algorithm to looks like pseudocode and be mode understandable.

Additionally, more specifically related to python, your code is supposed to follow some rule. Runtime code is supposed to be placed after `if __name__ == "__main__":` bloc.

Hope it helps you (take a look at the `findSolution` method):

```
class Polynom():
    """ A class representing a polynom that provides methods to find roots of the polynom. """
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, coefficients):
        """
        Constructor of the class.
        Takes a coeficient list [n, n-1, ..., n1, n0] that are the coefficients of a polynom.
        Example : 
            Polynom([1,2,3]) stand for : x² + 2x + 3
        """
        self.coefficients = coefficients
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def _dividers(self, coefficient):
        """Returns the list of the divider of a number by filtering the values in [1, 2, ... , |coefficient| ] that divide coefficient. """
        def filter_dividers(coefficient, candidate_values):
            # lambda function explanations : http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html
            return filter(lambda number : coefficient%number == 0, candidate_values)

        return list(filter_dividers(coefficient, range(1, abs(coefficient)+1)))
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def _gcd(self, x, y):
        """ Returns the greatest common diviser of the integers x and y """
        if y == 0:
            return abs(x)
        else:
            r = x%y
            return self._gcd(y, r)
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
    def _positiveAndNegativeCombinations(self, p_values, q_values):
        """
        Returns the list of positives and negatives combination of (p,q) pairs.
        Example : 
            [1,2]
                    -> [(1,4), (-1,4), (2,4), (-2,4), (1,5), (-1,5), (2,5), (-2,5)]
            [4,5]
        """
        def combinations(p, q_values):
            if len(q_values) == 1:
                return [(p, q_values[0])]
            else:
                return [(p, q_values[0])] + combinations(p, q_values[1:])

        result = []
        for p in p_values:
            p_combinations = combinations(p, q_values)
            for combination in p_combinations:
                result += [combination, (-1*combination[0], combination[1])]

        return result
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------          
    def __repr__(self):
        """ Representation of the object in a string for printing purpose."""

        def from_number_to_string_exposant(number):
            """
            Returns a string that is the number given as exposant.
            Example : 1 ->  "¹"
            """
            utf8_exposant = {"0":"⁰", "1":"¹", "2":"²", "3": "³", "4":"⁴", "5":"⁵", "6":"⁶", "7":"⁷", "8":"⁸", "9":"⁹"}
            string = str(number)
            result = ""
            for digit in string:
                result += utf8_exposant[digit]
            return result

        result = ""
        degree = 0
        coefficients = self.coefficients
        while coefficients != [] :
            coef, coefficients = coefficients[-1], coefficients[0:-1]
            result = "+ " +str(coef)+"x"+ from_number_to_string_exposant(degree) + result
            degree+=1
        return "<Polynom :" + result[1:] + " = 0 >"     
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def valueFor(self, value):
        """ Returns ture or false depending on the fact that the given value is or not a polunom's solution. """
        total_value = 0
        degree = 0
        coefficients = self.coefficients
        while coefficients != [] :
            coef, coefficients = coefficients[-1], coefficients[0:-1]
            total_value += coef*(value**degree)
            degree += 1
        return total_value
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def isSolution(self, value):
        """ Returns true or false depending if the given value is a polynom solution or not """
        return (self.valueFor(value) == 0)
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def findSolution(self):
        """
        Return a pair (p,q) that verify that p/q is a solution of this polynom. If no valid pair is find, return None.
        Call to this function come with log printing.
        """
        print("Search solution for ", self)

        a0 = self.coefficients[-1]
        aN = self.coefficients[0]
        if a0 == 0 or aN == 0:
            return None #algorithm is not applicable in this case.

        else:
            p_values = self._dividers(a0)
            q_values = self._dividers(aN)
            print("finded dividers of p :", p_values)
            print("finded dividers of q :", q_values)

            candidate_solutions = self._positiveAndNegativeCombinations(p_values,q_values)
            print("(p,q) pairs to evaluate are : \n\t",candidate_solutions)

            for candidate in candidate_solutions :
                candidate_value = 1.0 * candidate[0] / candidate[1]
                print("pair : ",candidate, " | value : ", candidate_value)
                if self.isSolution(candidate_value):
                    print()
                    return candidate
                else:
                    print("The pair ", candidate, "is invalid, replacing x by it leads to say that 0=", self.valueFor(candidate_value))

            return None
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


if __name__ == "__main__":
    poly = Polynom([2,1,-6])
    print(poly.findSolution())
```

Execute it with python3 (or change the print calls).

Arthur.

Answer (score 0):

https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577974-polynomial-factoring-using-rational-root-theorem/
Here's a working link.

```py
from math import ceil
listOfFactors = lambda n: {i for i in range(1,ceil(abs(n)/2)+1) if n%i == 0}
def removeDuplicates(mylist):
    if mylist:
        mylist.sort()
        last = mylist[-1]
        for i in range(len(mylist)-2, -1, -1):
            if last == mylist[i]:
                del mylist[i]
            else:
                last = mylist[i]
    return mylist

def polyRoots(polyListCoeff):
    allFactors = set()
    allFactorsListOld = list(allFactors.union(listOfFactors(polyListCoeff[0]),{polyListCoeff[0]},listOfFactors(polyListCoeff[-1]),{polyListCoeff[-1]}))
    allFactorsListOld.extend([-1*i for i in allFactorsListOld])
    allFactorsList = list()
    for k in allFactorsListOld:
        for j in allFactorsListOld:
            allFactorsList.append(k/j)
    allFactorsList = removeDuplicates(allFactorsList)
    polyListCoeff.reverse()
    roots = [i for i in allFactorsList if sum([pow(i,j)*polyListCoeff[j] for j in range(0,len(polyListCoeff))]) == 0]
    factorList = list()
    for i in roots:
        if i<0:
            factorList.append("(x+{})".format(-i))
        else:
            factorList.append("(x-{})".format(i))
    return "".join(factorList)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    polyRoots([1,0,-4])
#   '(x+2.0)(x-2.0)'
```